# How can I improve build time of Angular 5 project using Docker?

Tags: angular, docker, dockerfile, angular-cli, angular5

I’m trying to improve the build time of my automation. Right now it takes 14 mins just to build the front-end.

[image]

---

This is what I got so far

**web.dockerfile**

```
### STAGE 1: Build ###
FROM node:9.3.0-alpine as builder

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm set progress=false && npm config set depth 0 && npm cache clean --force

## Storing node modules on a separate layer will prevent unnecessary npm installs at each build
RUN npm i
RUN mkdir /web
RUN cp -R ./node_modules ./web

WORKDIR /web

COPY . .

RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --prod --build-optimizer

### STAGE 2: Setup ###

FROM nginx:1.13.8-alpine

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY site.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

COPY --from=builder /web/dist /usr/share/nginx/html/

RUN touch /var/run/nginx.pid && \
  chown -R nginx:nginx /var/run/nginx.pid && \
  chown -R nginx:nginx /var/cache/nginx && \
  chown -R nginx:nginx /usr/share/nginx/html

USER nginx
```

> RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --prod --build-optimizer

This line above is taking so long almost the entire 99% of the build time.

---

*.angular-cli.json*

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "web"
  },
  "apps": [{
    "root": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "assets": [
      "assets",
      "favicon.ico"
    ],
    "index": "index.html",
    "main": "main.ts",
    "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
    "test": "test.ts",
    "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
    "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
    "prefix": "app",
    "styles": [
      "styles.css",
      "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
      "../node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
      "../src/assets/css/style.css",
      "../src/assets/css/colors/blue.css"

    ],
    "scripts": [
      "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
      "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
      "../node_modules/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js",
      "../node_modules/pace-js/pace.min.js"
    ],
    "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
    "environments": {
      "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
      "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
    }
  }],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [{
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

## Environment

*DockerCloud connect to my AWS*

*AWS : EC2 micro*

---

## Result

This dockerfile works perfectly and it build success.

But it takes about 14 minutes to build. Is it possible to improve this? Is it because of my instance have too little processor?

Comment: How long does it take to build locally?

Comment: It takes about `2 mins` to build locally, just to build my web only.

Comment: Is your build server cpu/memory bound? Maybe local you can power through it but the build server is doing 10 builds at once and just doesn't have the extra cpu/memory to do it any faster.

Comment: My build server is only perform this automated build.

Comment: Can you post details about the OS you are using, docker version? Also logs of the build would be of some help

Comment: Please show your Build pipeline definition. As far i understood you taling about bitbucket buildpipeline speed problems?

Comment: Tarballs. Just set up the environment the way you want on a host machine, tar it up, and untar it inside the container.

Comment: Any update on this? I validated and node_modules or ignores are not the problem. Problem is the build itself. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17017  . On my case the `npm run build`  eats up all my ram T_T. Without docker, cpu/ram consumption of the build is high but ends.

Answer (score 4):

**[TL;DR]**

- Use volumes to store node_modules and .npm
- Parallelize parts of your process (e.g. tests)
- Be careful when using relative paths
- Do not copy your entire project with `COPY . .` . Relative path issues and possible information leaks.
- Create a separate image containing only core dependencies for building and testing (e.g. npm, java, chrome-driver, libgconf2).
- Configure pipelines to use this image
- Let the CI clone the repo and copy your project into the container for building and testing
- Archive built files (e.g. `dist`) and tag based on failure rates
- Create a new image with just enough things to run your built files.

**[LONG VERSION]**

There is a good chance that your npm dependencies are being re-downloaded and/or your docker images are being rebuilt for every build you run.

Rather than copying files into a docker image, it would be better to mount volumes for modules and cache so that additional dependencies included later doesn't need to be downloaded again. Typical directories that you should consider creating volumes for are npm_modules (one for global and one for local) and .npm (cache).

Your `package.json` is being copied into root `/` and the same `package.json` is being copied into `/web` with `COPY . .`.

<s>The initial run of `npm i` is installing into `/` and you're running it again for `/web`. You're downloading dependencies twice but are the modules in `/` going to be used for anything? Regardless, you appear to be using the same package.json in both `npm i` and `ng build`, so the same thing is being done twice,</s> *( [EDIT] - It would seem that `ng build` doesn't redownload packages*) but node_modules isn't available in `/` so the `npm i` command creates another one and re-downloads all packages.

You create a `web` directory in root `/` but there are other commands instructing to relative paths `./web`. Are you certain that things are running in the right places? There is no guarantee that programs would be looking in the directories you want them to if you use relative paths. While it may appear to work for this image, the same practice will not be consistent across other images that may have different initial work directories.

[may or may not be relevant information]

Although I'm not using Bitbucket for automating builds, I faced a similar issue when running Jenkins pipelines. Jenkins placed the project in a different directory so that every time it runs, all the dependencies would be downloaded again. I initially thought the project would be in `/home/agent/project` but it was actually placed elsewhere. I found the directory where the project was copied to by using the `pwd` and `npm cache verify` command in a build step, then mounted the volumes to the correct places. You can view the output in the logs generated on builds.

You can view the output by expanding the section within the pipelines page.

[image]

If the image is being rebuilt on every run, build your image separately then push the image to a registry. Configure the pipeline file to use your image instead. You should try to use already available base images whenever possible unless there are other dependencies you need that are unavailable in the base image (things like alpine's apk packages and not npm. npm dependencies can be stored in volumes). If you're going to use a public registry, do not store any files that may contain sensitive data. Configure your pipeline so that things are mounted with volumes and/or uses secrets.

A basic restructure on the test and build steps.

```
       Image on Docker Hub
              |
              |
           ---|-------------------------------------|
           |                       |                |
           V                       V                |
Commit -- build (no test) ---> e2e tests (no build)-]--+--> archive build --> (deploy/merge/etc)
                         |           _______________|  ^
                         |           v                 |
                         |-> unit tests (no build)---->|
```

You don't need to follow it entirely, but it should give you an idea on how you could use parallel steps to separate things and improve completion times.

Comment: Thank-you very much for the answer, and suggestions about the security for sensitive information when doing `COPY . . `

What should I use instead ? Can you please suggest a better Dockerfile how mine should look like?

Comment: I don't really understand, or know how when you said, 
`Use volumes to store node_modules and .npm` or 
`Parallelize parts of your process (e.g. tests)`

Can you please show a snippet of code or links or explanation of those points ?

Comment: You can use `COPY . .` if you're aware of what you're copying. Some people might leave passwords/certificates/keys in the same project directory and you don't want these copied over then pushed to a registry that could be made public. You can use a combination of [`.gitignore`](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/gitignore) to prevent files from being pushed to your git repository, and [`.dockerignore`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) to prevent docker from copying the files into your container. I think it's just better to be explicit in what's copied.

Comment: You don't need to copy your project files when creating the image. Files can be copied over when the container is run, or mounted using volumes. As for parallel steps, it doesn't appear to be implemented in Bitbucket's pipelines yet. It is available in Travic CI and Jenkins so I assumed Bitbucket's pipelines would support it as well but it appears that it doesn't.   
On the upside, I just learned Bitbucket Pipelines can now cache dependencies so no need for volumes. You can read it from [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/caching-dependencies-895552876.html)